# Being able to Order By After a Group BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to order these terms after I group by in a sql query
The SQL query works on my last line of the GROUP BY
but adding the oder by causes an error.
Help identifying what is wrong would be helpful.

Examples of doing a group by and a successful order by would be useful

```
GROUP by new.flights and
ORDER BY new.flights DESC and new.pilots DESC;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: When GROUP BY, you're only allowed to ORDER BY select list items.

Answer (score 0):

You have boolean operations.  I think you intend:

```
GROUP BY new.flights
ORDER BY new.flights DESC;
```

The part about `new.pilots DESC` doesn't make sense.  You have one row per distinct value of `flights` so a second `ORDER BY` key doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove AND and replace by ',' in teh order by clause

```
GROUP by new.flights and
ORDER BY new.flights DESC ,new.pilots DESC;
```